# How to share RSpec let variables between shared contexts?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to DRY my RSpec request specs by using shared contexts. I'd like to share `let` variables between shared contexts so that they inherit and extend from one another.

```
Rspec.shared_context 'JSON request' do
  let(:headers) do
    {
      'Accept' => 'application/json'
    }
  end
end

Rspec.shared_context 'Authenticated request' do
  let(:headers) do
    super().merge('Authorization' => "Bearer #{token}")
  end
end

Rspec.describe 'user management' do
  let(:token) { create(:oauth_token) }

  include_context 'JSON request'
  include_context 'Authenticated request'

  it 'responds with a 200 ok' do
    get '/user', headers: headers
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
  end
end
```

Declaring `token` works as expected, but using `super()` to override `headers` returns a `NoMethodError` suggesting `super()` is nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to refer to the currently defined value of a `let` variable in a `let` block. (When I try it I get "stack level too deep".) I'd do what you're trying to do this way:

```
Rspec.shared_context 'JSON request' do
  let(:common_headers) do
    {
      'Accept' => 'application/json'
    }
  end
  let(:headers) { common_headers }
end

Rspec.shared_context 'Authenticated request' do
  let(:headers) do
    common_headers.merge('Authorization' => "Bearer #{token}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `super()` to get the value of a predefined `let`:

```rb
RSpec.shared_context 'common' do
  let(:foo) { 'foo' }
end

RSpec.describe 'test' do
  include_context 'common'

  context 'reversed' do
    let(:foo) { super().reverse }

    it 'works' do
      expect(foo).to eq('oof')
    end
  end
end
```